# Attaching Selenium Webdrive to CefSharp browser docked on second form

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cefsharp

What i'm trying to do is use the Selenium WebDriver to control Chrome instead of using Javascript, so basically combine `Selenium` & `cefsharp` so I can use `.sendKeys()`.

I have docked the browser in a panel here `panelBrowserMain.Controls.Add(browser);` and read the official docs here: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver.md this example loads a seperate client `cefClient.exe` where as I just want to interact using my embedded browser located here `panelBrowserMain.Controls.Add(browser);`.

When I do a testing at `LinkLabel1_LinkClicked` to show the page source i'm getting `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` errors, so the `_driver` is not being assigned (even though I do in the code)

I have Google'd quite a bit and their is hardly any information or solutions that I can see, is my code even correct, any help or tips would be appreciated.

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace projectname
{
    public partial class FormBrowser : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        private ChromeDriver _driver;

        private void FormBrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Fix for the formClosing event not firing.
                FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(FormBrowser_FormClosed);
                Text = string.Format("Chromium: {0}, CEF: {1}, CefSharp: {2}", Cef.ChromiumVersion, Cef.CefVersion, Cef.CefSharpVersion);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ClassHelpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
        }

        private void LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ClassHelpers.ReturnMessage(_driver.PageSource);
                //_driver.FindElement(By.Name("user[profile_attributes][first_name]")).SendKeys("UserName");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ClassHelpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
        }

        public FormBrowser(string[] sites, string mode, FormMain formMain, ClassProject project)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeBrowser(sites, project);
        }

        public void InitializeBrowser(string[] sites, ClassProject project)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
                {
                    // CEF.
                    CefSettings settings = new CefSettings()
                    {
                        LogFile = "cef/cefsharp.log",
                        CachePath = Path.GetFullPath("cef/cache/"),
                        UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
                    };

                    settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = Path.GetFullPath("cef/cefsharp/CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe");
                    settings.LocalesDirPath = Path.GetFullPath("cef/cefsharp/locales");
                    settings.ResourcesDirPath = Path.GetFullPath("cef/cefsharp/");
                    settings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088;
                    settings.UserDataPath = Path.GetFullPath("cef/cefsharp/cefuserdata");

                    if (project.Proxy != "ip:port")
                    {
                        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", project.Proxy);
                    }

                    Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
                    // CEF.

                    sitesCount = sites.Count();

                    // Load in the first URL that was checked, which is index 0.
                    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(sites[counter])
                    {
                        MenuHandler = new MyCustomMenuHandler()
                    };

                    browser.AddressChanged += OnBrowserAddressChanged;
                    panelBrowserMain.Controls.Add(browser);
                    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    browserMain.Text = sites[counter];

                    // Selenium WebDriver.
                    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions
                    {
                        DebuggerAddress = "localhost:8088"
                    };
                    options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");

                    ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                    service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

                    _driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
                    // Selenium WebDriver.

                }
                else
                {
                    // IMPORTANT: Cef is already initialized, do not do it again.
                    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(sites[counter])
                    {
                        MenuHandler = new MyCustomMenuHandler()
                    };
                    browser.AddressChanged += OnBrowserAddressChanged;
                    panelBrowserMain.Controls.Add(browser);
                    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    browserMain.Text = sites[counter];

                    // Add the code here once we get it working above.
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ClassHelpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lots of duplicate code that ideally should be removed,  make your code easier to review also. What do you mean by docked  on a second form? Where's the second form? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi amaitland what I mean is, on my main WinForms app I have a button "Load Browser" this is where the panel docking happens, it's not a seperate browser.exe but built in, in the example on bitbucket it's like it wants a binary cefClient.exe instead of using the browser shown on the form (if this makes sense :)) cleaning up code too, thank you.

Comment: Have you confirmed your ChromeDriver instance has been created?